# Conjugate addition of alkyl groups to α,β-unsaturated Aldehyde

Tags: organic-chemistry

why the conjugate addition of an alkyl or other organic group to an α,β-unsaturated aldehyde is not available while ketones can? (for example of addition of lithium diorganocopper reagent, R2CuLi)

Answer (score 1):

Quoting M. Mauduit et al in Comprehensive Organic Synthesis (2nd Ed, 2014) from  [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/alpha-beta-unsaturated-aldehyde)

> α,β-Unsaturated aldehydes represent certainly the most challenging Michael acceptor concerning the asymmetric copper-catalyzed conjugate addition of organometallic nucleophiles. This is mainly because of their higher reactivity that allows the undesired formation of 1,2-adducts as well as the aldol by-product.

Further reading of this article reports strategies to allow 1,4 addition.